# Работа с базами данных из браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли простой способ наладить взаимодействие программы, которая работает в браузере (HTML, CSS, JS) с базой данных (MySQL, SQLite) на локальном компьютере без глубокого изучения технологий backend-а?

Пояснение вопроса: есть необходимость написать программку для рабочих нужд. Логика программки не сложная, но требуется взаимодействие с БД (тоже не сложное) на локальном компьютере. Самый простой вариант сделать все на Python, но хочется красивый интерфейс, не изучая специально дополнительно что-то новое. А из известных мне технологий (на самом новичковом уровне, естественно) tkinter (Python) и HTML+CSS+JS в браузере. Изучать даже основы backend долго, к тому же для целей проекта никаких путей/авторизаций/валидаций токенов и т.д не нужно.

Comment: Тогда на сервере либо нужно делать запрос к БД из пхп файла, либо небольшую апишку, а уже через запрос в JS получать информацию.

Comment: *"существует ли простой способ без глубокого изучения"* --- на любом серверном языке можно это сделать.  Самый простой вариант без геморра - php

Comment: Можно nodejs+express поднять.

Comment: Никто вам не мешает сделать бэкэнд на одном языке, а фронтенд на другом.

Comment: А как насчёт Web Storage или IndexedDB?

Comment: А вот это интересный вариант. Спасибо!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Самый простой вариант сделать все на Python, но хочется красивый
> интерфейс, не изучая специально дополнительно что-то новое.

Ничего не мешает сделать "красивый интерфейс" с использованием питона.
А так, как вариант, можно начать изучение [электрона](https://www.electronjs.org/)